# How i can make an iframe to fit in my page?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I mean to remove the margin's and the frameborders. For this element:
[image: This is the iframe]

And I wanna fit like the default footer.

```css
.footer-frame {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="footer-frame" src="URL"></iframe>

<!-- Footer code  (Bootstrap)-->
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="URL">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row mainFooter">
<footer class="col-md-12">
<p>
 &copy;2016 <a href="URL" id="link3">McCore</a> Minden jog fentartva
| <a href="javascript:;" id="link3">MrAnonymusz</a>
</p>
</footer>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Footer code  (Bootstrap)-->
```

This is the default looking of the footer (i wanna look like this):
[image]

Comment: your code snippet error?

Comment: nope... I just added it for example

Comment: is url from iframe from same domain as ur site?

Comment: root/assests/components/footer.php

Comment: what r u trying to do here?, if u just wanna add footer to that page why dont u just include(footer.php) in that particular page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help u to clear ur margins n borders

```css
iframe {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://getbootstrap.com/"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: okay i tried but i have a little margin-bottom how I can remove that ?

Comment: is it from iframe or the page which u link via iframe?

Comment: i resolved that, but how i can make to open links (not _blank) in the same page but not in the iframe ?

Comment: Are you having the link in iframe and have to open them in the page. If so use, `_top`.

Comment: another question... now I tried to add my header but i can't set the height what's the problem with that ?

Comment: @MrAnonymusz if u think this answer helps u to solved ur problem u can mark it as answer

Comment: dont include iframes everywhere its not good approach just to include ur header and footer, instead use php and include that particular page

Comment: like `<?php include 'footer.php';?>` see basic ex [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)